# Finding a value within cells linked from another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

Today I have a new problem with the .Find function. I am trying to do .Find through a worksheet that has cells linked from another sheet. 
I have ws1 which contains a header row of linked dates from ws2. As an example:
ws1 A1 cell formula is =ws2!$A$1, ws1 B1 formula is =ws2!$A$2. ws2 contains dates in column A.

I am using .Find in ws1 to find the value displayed within ComboBox1 on a userform(i.e. ComboBox1.Value). ComboBox1 source is linked directly to ws2 A column and the value on update is changed to a dd-mmm-yy format.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub TestSub()
Dim colRng As Range

With Worksheets("ws1").Range("A1:FZ200")
    Set colRng = .Find(CDate(ComboBox1.Value))
End With
MsgBox "colRng is: " + colRng.Address

End Sub
```

This gives me Run Time Error 91: Object or With Block variable not set. On Debug the value of colRng is Nothing and not a Range.

The only thing I can think of is that the linked cells are messing up the formatting but I am not sure how to fix that issue. Any ideas?

UPDATE: I tested the .Find function in my statement with a string which does work.

```
With Worksheets("ws1").Range("A1:FZ200")
    Set colRng = .Find(ComboBox1.Value)
End With
MsgBox "colRng is: " + colRng.Address
```

I do not know how to go about finding the value within a cell if it is linked from another sheet however. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the `.Find()` has not found anything and this is the reason.
Do you know what you are looking for? If you write `CDate(ComboBox1.Value)` does it get the expected value?

In general, to avoid this error in case that `.Find()` has not found anything, this is the work around:

```
If Not colRng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "colRng is: " + colRng.Address
End If
```

Comment: Yes on debug CDate(ComboBox1.Value) has the correct value but .Find does not find a cell with the value. 

I dont know if that is because the cells it is searching through contain linked formulas such as =ws1!$A$1. I have tried to force the .Find function to search xlValues and xlFormulas but neither of these have worked.

Comment: @JoeyScott - write in the combobox some value, that is not date. E.g. `"MyTest"`. Then write `"MyTest"` on the range where it can look for it. Execute the code. If it works, the problem is in the date format.

Comment: Okay I did that and removed the CDate. This worked. How would I go about finding the value of linked cells? I cannot seem to find the answer to this anywhere.

Comment: @JoeyScott - the fact that the range is with linked formulas from another sheet is really not important, if you are looking at `xlValues`. It is probably the format of the date which is causing the problems.

Comment: Shouldnt CDate fix that problem? I dont understand how the formating of the date could be wrong with CDate.

Comment: Probably the cells in the Excel range are not dates. Idk, tough to guess w/o data.

Answer (score 1):

So dates can be hard to deal with in Excel as they can be construed as integers or strings (and formatted with different timezones)

For an easy fix the following code should allow one line to be uncommented to find the respective dates or strings

```
Private Sub TestSub()
    Dim colRng As Range

    With Worksheets("ws1")
        sFind = ComboBox1.Value
        'Set colRng = .Range("A1:FZ200").Find(CDate(sFind), LookIn:=xlValues)
        'Set colRng = .Range("A1:FZ200").Find(Format(CDate(sFind), "dd/mm/yyyy"), LookIn:=xlValues)
    End With
    If Not colRng Is Nothing Then Debug.Print "colRng is: " + colRng.Address

End Sub
```

As a more complete answer, you could use the following generic FindAll function...

```
Private Sub FindAllDates()
    Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, AllRng As Range, sFind As String

    With Worksheets("ws1")
        sFind = ComboBox1.Value
        Set Rng1 = FindAll(CDate(sFind), .Range("A1:FZ200"), LookIn:=xlValues)
        Set Rng2 = FindAll(Format(CDate(sFind), "dd/mm/yyyy"), .Range("A1:FZ200"), LookIn:=xlValues)
    End With
    Set AllRng = CombineRange(Rng1, Rng2)
    If Not AllRng Is Nothing Then Debug.Print "AllRng is: " + AllRng.Address

End Sub

Function CombineRange(R1 As Range, R2 As Range) As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set CombineRange = R1
    If Not R2 Is Nothing Then Set CombineRange = Application.Union(R1, R2)
    If CombineRange Is Nothing Then Set CombineRange = R2
End Function

Function FindAll(What, _
    Optional SearchWhat As Variant, _
    Optional LookIn, _
    Optional LookAt, _
    Optional SearchOrder, _
    Optional SearchDirection As XlSearchDirection = xlNext, _
    Optional MatchCase As Boolean = False, _
    Optional MatchByte, _
    Optional SearchFormat) As Range

    'LookIn can be xlValues or xlFormulas, _
     LookAt can be xlWhole or xlPart, _
     SearchOrder can be xlByRows or xlByColumns, _
     SearchDirection can be xlNext, xlPrevious, _
     MatchCase, MatchByte, and SearchFormat can be True or False. _
     Before using SearchFormat = True, specify the appropriate settings for the Application.FindFormat _
     object; e.g. Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "General;-General;""-"""

    Dim SrcRange As Range
    If IsMissing(SearchWhat) Then
        Set SrcRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    ElseIf TypeOf SearchWhat Is Range Then
        Set SrcRange = IIf(SearchWhat.Cells.Count = 1, SearchWhat.Parent.UsedRange, SearchWhat)
    ElseIf TypeOf SearchWhat Is Worksheet Then
        Set SrcRange = SearchWhat.UsedRange
    Else: SrcRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    End If
    If SrcRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function

    'get the first matching cell in the range first
    With SrcRange.Areas(SrcRange.Areas.Count)
        Dim FirstCell As Range: Set FirstCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
    End With

    Dim CurrRange As Range: Set CurrRange = SrcRange.Find(What:=What, After:=FirstCell, LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, _
        SearchDirection:=SearchDirection, MatchCase:=MatchCase, MatchByte:=MatchByte, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)

    If Not CurrRange Is Nothing Then
        Set FindAll = CurrRange
        Do
            Set CurrRange = SrcRange.Find(What:=What, After:=CurrRange, LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, _
            SearchDirection:=SearchDirection, MatchCase:=MatchCase, MatchByte:=MatchByte, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)
            If CurrRange Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            If Application.Intersect(FindAll, CurrRange) Is Nothing Then
                Set FindAll = Application.Union(FindAll, CurrRange)
            Else: Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, these answers do work to find the correct dates and I know that Vityata said that linked cell values should not matter but the problem is indeed because I have linked the cells. After a lot of testing, I can always get this to work if the range of cells I am searching through does not have linked data but once I remove the data from the cells and link them from another sheet I can no longer get .Find to work. I am not sure if this is a bug but I have been messing around with it for a while.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: For links, you need to specify within the find function: LookIn:=xlValues